# Oracle save mandarin characters with we8iso8859p1

Tags: oracle, java, jdbc

Im trying to save Mandarin characters into Oracle instance database 11g.
Field datatype - NVARCHAR2 ;
NLS_LANG - AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1

If I change NLS_LANG, it will affect other data already in this huge database but I need it to support manadarin as well.
Im also searching for some way if available on JAVA side while inserting these characters into DB.
Please help.

Comment: NLS_LANG is not relevant here. Relevant is which character set you chose for the NVARCHAR when the instance was initialized

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `NLS_LANG` value does not affect any data in the database. However setting character set to `WE8ISO8859P1` will not work.

When you set `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1` then you tell the database "The client uses character set WE8ISO8859P1." Thus any Mandarin characters will not be accepted by the database because they are not supported by WE8ISO8859P1.

Use `AL32UTF8` or any other character set which supports Mandarin, for example `ZHS32GB18030`

Apart from that, **Java does not use the `NLS_LANG` setting at all**, see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643):

> Starting from Oracle Database 10g, the NLS_LANG variable is no longer
>   part of the JDBC globalization mechanism. The JDBC driver does not
>   check NLS environment. So, setting it has no effect.

Please have a look at this document how to setup Unicode in Java environment.

Of course, the database **NCHAR** Character Set has to support Mandarin. Usually this is set to default `AL16UTF16`, so I assume that's not the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for this.
 I have NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16 . Should this help in saving mandarin characters?
Just for information, if I directly edit, copy-paste mandarin into NVARCHAR2 field of DB, then it displays as it is on screen, The problem is only in saving.

I have another test DB where NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8 , but there also Im not able to save mandarin. I guess there might be some JDBC driver settings change also required.

Comment: Yes, `AL16UTF16` is fine. But `AL32UTF8` is also fine. Sorry, I am not familiar with Java where I could help you.